# Evaluation of the OPE coefficients in Peskin&Schroeder's book

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I was reading the book by Peskin&Schroeder and at page 616 the authors write the operator product expansion of the quarks electromagnetic current $J^{\mu} (x) J^{\nu} (0)$ as:

$ J^{\mu} (x) J^{\nu} (0) \sim C_{\mu \nu}^{1} (x) 1 + C_{\mu \nu}^{q \overline{q}} (x) q \overline{q}(0) + C_{\mu \nu}^{F^2} (x) \left(F_{\alpha \beta}^a \right)^2 (0) + ...$,

then they move to Fourier space and by the Ward identity they get the result:

$ -e^2 \int d^4x e^{iqx} J^{\mu} (x) J^{\nu} (0) \sim -ie^2 \left( q^2 g^{\mu \nu} - q^{\mu} q^{\nu} \right) \left[ c^{1} (q^2) 1 + c^{q \overline{q}} (q^2) q \overline{q}(0) + c^{F^2} (q^2) \left(F_{\alpha \beta}^a \right)^2 (0) + ... \right]$.

So far so good. My question regards the way they claim the coefficients $c^i$ are calculated. Peskin&Schroeder write: "The OPE coefficients $c^i(q^2)$ can be computed from Feynman diagrams. As shown in Fig. 18.5, the coefficient of the operator 1 is the sum of diagrams with no external legs other than the current insertions."

I do not understand why. I assume what one should do is taking the braket $<\Omega| T ... |\Omega>$ on both sides of the equation. This generates the expansion with no external legs on the LHS: $- e^2 <\Omega| T J^{\mu}J^{\nu} (q) |\Omega>$, but on the RHS we get $-ie^2 \left( q^2 g^{\mu \nu} - q^{\mu} q^{\nu} \right) \left[ c^{1} (q^2) + c^{q \overline{q}} (q^2) <\Omega| q \overline{q}(0) |\Omega> + c^{F^2} (q^2) <\Omega| \left(F_{\alpha \beta}^a \right)^2 (0) |\Omega> + ... \right]$, so we have not isolated the coefficient $c^1(q^2)$, because in QCD we know $<\Omega| q \overline{q}(0) |\Omega> = \Lambda_{QCD}^3$, so we have not isolated the coefficient $c^1(q^2)$.